# Is it possible to check if two arrays are not equal

Tags: java, arrays

I'm aware of the fact that I could just do a:

```
while(Arrays.equals(array1, array2))
```

and then just write the code needed in the `else` statement.

Is there any other way to check if they are not equal?

Comment: It's `Arrays` not `arrays`.

Comment: `while` has no `else` statement in java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whats wrong with

> if( !Arrays.equals(array1, array2) )

`array1.equals(array2)` is the same as `array1 == array2`, 
i.e. is it the same array. And it's not what most people expect.

`Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` compares the contents of the arrays.

Comment: I'm so sorry i thought this didn't work wih Strings but it seems like it does thanks!

Comment: as long as the result is an boolean, you can do any logical operation on it! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want a `while`, but an if, since a `while` doesn't have an `else`-clause. You can use a negation operator (`!`) to check if the arrays are not equal like this:

```
if(!Arrays.equals(array1, array2))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if (!Arrays.equals(array1, array2))
```

Or is that what you mean in your example?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !Arrays.equals(array1, array2) )
    // their contents are not equal
```